# Silverlight OOB icons not appearing on the Windows 8 desktops

Tags: silverlight, icons, windows-8, desktop, out-of-browser

I have a Silverlight 5 Project compiled in the VS2012. I've set all png icons for the out-of-browser properly. If I test the Installation in the e.g. Windows XP I see all these icons everywhere (on the desktop, in the start menu, taskbar, etc.)
Windows 8 shows the icon also everywhere except on the metro and classic desktop.

Is this a bug in the Silverlight, or is any workaround for the Windows 8 available?

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm this problem. I installed an OOB application to **Windows 7** and had no problems. In **Windows 8** I can see the correct icon in install dialog and on the upper left corner of OOB window but in start menu and on desktop the icon is white paper.

I checked the path of the icon:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Silverlight\OutOfBrowser\2301909557.app.url.com\2301909557.app.url.com.ico
```

I tried to use another .ICO file and had no problems. Then I changed it back to original. I could see the correct icon in preview window but when I accepted the changes the icon changed to white paper again.

Maybe there is something wrong with the .ICO file?

Comment: if you open up the .ico in an icon editor (say http://icofx.ro/ trial) does it contain 64x64 version? can you compare with other .ico files on Win8?

Comment: at some forum an issue with PNG interlace setting not being supported on Win7 was mentioned, may be related too (not sure if the IDE or the deployment was on Win7)

Comment: No, it was compiled and deployed on the Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Windows 7 a couple months ago. I fixed it by convert the `png` image to `ico` file.

Comment: do you mean you passed .ico files to Visual Studio's dialog that asks for the various sizes of the icon graphics?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem then fixed it by adding a 64x64 icon to the ico file
(I thought it worked but now I have a blank page again)

Comment: probably you built/deployed your project again and it removed the 64x64 version from inside the icon file again? If that is the case then one can add a post-build action probably to fix the .ico inside the .xap file. Only hope post-build actions are exectuted before publishing (which does call build automatically), but I guess they should

Answer (score 0):

at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/759bd857-ce84-45a2-8b38-4cd83744ea2b/oob-icon-on-windows-8 they say you can set OOB app to use elevated rights to fix the issue, but find it strange, plus using rights elevation just for that isn't a solution (see more there on why it's not acceptable)